# Help with Blueprint CSS box class

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

I started playing with Blueprint CSS tonight and things are going pretty well. Up until I started to use the .box class, and adding a dropshadow to it. I ended up creating my own class to apply the shadows, but now my column count seems to be off. Instead of the normal 24 columns, I can only use 23. If i use 24 columns, the overflow turns on and I get scroll bars.

The reason I made my own class was because if i applied the shadows to the .box class, I would run into the overflow issue. I did some research and found that I needed to create a child div for the box class. If i removed my shadows, things worked great.

Both the CSS and the HTML are located here: http://pastie.org/1608550

I can move forward as is, but I'm concerned this will cause issues down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by removing the .box div completely. I updated the pastie with the functional results.